# Modify the function to return true if both arguments are true, and return false otherwise

Tags: javascript, function, syntax-error

Keep getting Uncaught SyntaxError: Missing catch or finally after try

Why is this wrong?

```
function areBothTrue(bool1, bool2) {
  `return bool1 && bool2;`
}

}


console.log(areBothTrue(true, false), '<-- should be false');
console.log(areBothTrue(true, true), '<-- should be true');
```

Comment: Did you read carefully this: **Missing `catch` or `finally` after `try`**. So please, include the `try` block or the rest of the code.

Comment: What is the "try" block? Forgive me if I sound stupid but I am very new to this so how do I do that?

Comment: You can read about that here: [try ... catch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch)

Comment: You have an extra `}`. Why is the return statement inside backticks? That's used for template strings.

Answer (score 1):

Your code isn't complete. And the use of ` isn't required.

Here's the correct command

```
function areBothTrue(bool1, bool2) {
  if (bool1 && bool2){
    return true
  }
  else{
    return false
  }
}

console.log(areBothTrue(true, false), '<-- should be false');
console.log(areBothTrue(true, true), '<-- should be true');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine for me, instead of the extra curly bracket, which goes after the function definition and backticks surrounded return statement `function areBothTrue(bool1, bool2) {  return bool1 && bool2; }`. It works just fine, you could check yourself putting it in a browser, for example, chrome console.

`const areBothTrue = function(bool1, bool2) {
  return bool1 && bool2;
};

console.log(areBothTrue(true, false));`
Probably your error goes from another part of the code you didn't post.
Cheers

Comment: What about this one... I test ran it and it comes back fine but when I try to submit I get the true and false is undefined.    function isInteger(num) 
var res = "";  
res = res + Number.isInteger(1)+ ": 1<br>";
res = res + Number.isInteger(1.5)+ ": 1.5<br>";
}

{----------this one is running correct on test platrom but not in Lambda Challenge